# How to have a div be positioned relative to its parent, but float above it's siblings?

Tags: html, css

I have one div - the #container - that stretches across the window, filled with a graphic. I need a bar to float over the container div on the right side. If I use `position:absolute` and `right:0`, the div is positioned according to the window, not the #container div.

If I use `position:relative`, then the div is positioned according to the #container div but still takes up space and won't be hovering over the #container content.

Here is a JSFiddle that I made with my attempt.

http://jsfiddle.net/y8LCu/

**NOTE** that I do not want to use `float:right`, because that would keep the side div in the flow of the content, which I do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the parent's `position` to `relative`

```
#container
{
  position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I got it the way you wanted it?

http://jsfiddle.net/y8LCu/9/

You needed to make the parent `position: relative` and if you don't want the overflow you need `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 2):

`position:absolute;` allows you to position an element compared to any positioned ancestor.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>


.parent { position : relative; }

.child { position : absolute; }
```

Now, child will position itself based on the parent.
If the parent doesn't have a `position` set, then it will look at the `position` of the grandparent...

...and on and on, and if none of them have a `position` set, then it will look at the position of the actual web-page.

Also, if you have multiple `position`ed elements (whether relative/absolute/fixed) near the same place, and you want them to overlap in an order you set in CSS, and not in the order of which is set on the page last...

...then you also need to start using `z-index` (which only works on positioned elements).

The higher it is, the more stuff it stacks on top of.